# Use multiple where condition in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, where-clause, codeigniter-3

i have a select field named categories[] with multiple select and i written one on change function so on change fuction it will go the controller as an array of id's now what i want is i want to select foods from mysql table with these categories

```
<select name="categories[]">
    <?php 
      foreach ($category as $c) {

    ?>
     <option value="<?php echo $c->category_id; ?>"><?php echo $c->category_name;?></option>
    <?php
       }

     ?>
</select>
```

controller

```
    public function get_foods(){

       $categories = $this->input->post(NULL,true);
       $sql = $this->subscription->get_foods($categories);
       $result = array(

                    'result' => $sql

       );
      echo json_encode($result);
    }
```

and model

```
    public function get_foods($id){

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM food_category fc
            LEFT JOIN food f ON fc.food_id=f.food_id
            WHERE f.food_status = 1 AND
            fc.category_id = $id
            ORDER BY f.food_id DESC";
    $query = $this->db->query($sql);
    return $query->result_array();

}
```

i want to fetch all the foods in these categories, so i think i should have to use some multiple where condition ?

Comment: What is the question or doubt here ? Please explain

Comment: What you should post is the codes of `get_foods()` function. That is what we need.

Comment: sorry @rmondesilva

Answer (score 0):

You just need to store category with each food and when you get the foods you can use a where condition :

```
$this->db->where('category',$category);
```

Comment: i can use this one if the $category is an array of category id's@PHP Geek

Comment: No it is not compulsory as $category is an array. It may be just a variable.

Comment: no i have an array , thats what i want to use multiple where@PHP Geek

Comment: then use $this->db->where($category);

Answer (score 0):

use the where columns in () sql function for this.

for detail description on it. find here
    http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp

Answer (score 0):

If this can help, I think you need to post the categories one by one, then get it and put it in one array. Here is a code that may help

```
public function get_foods()
{
    $result = array();
    foreach($this->input->post('categories') as $c)
    {
        $result[] = $this->subscription->get_foods($c);
    }
    echo json_encode($result);
}
```

and for the model I suggest making use of AR of CI

```
public function get_foods($category)
{
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('food_category as fc');
    $this->db->join('food as f','fc.food_id = f.food_id','left');
    $this->db->where('f.food_status', '1');
    $this->db->where('fc.category_id',$category);        
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

First we make an empty array, then using the foreach in post we get all the foods per category then return them inside the result array.

Hope this helps and if there's any error in the sql since I may have forgotten some of the join, I'd be willing to help again.